# Arduino serial communication working strange

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am writing a C# program that has to communicate with an Arduino. Basically it sends data to it and I should be able to read in the serial monitor.

C# code:

```cs
if (errCheck[i].IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault() == true)
    err = "1"+err;
else 
    err = "0"+err;
_serialPort.Write("<16,"+ Convert.ToUInt32(err,2) + ">");
```

Arduino code:

```cpp
void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    //strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    //strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    integerFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer


    switch (integerFromPC) {
        //all cases         
        case 16: //managing errors
            delay(10);
            strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
            uint32_tFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);     
            errors=uint32_tFromPC;
            Serial.print("errors Updated" );
```

When the last checkbox is checked (so my binary string is 1 and 31 0's) the serial monitor reads `7F FF FF FF` instead of `80 00 00 00`.
I have tried using `ulong` but it doesn't seem to work either, any ideas?

Comment: I've tried using uint 64 and if in the arduino code i put errors=1and31 0's it works

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to convert the String to int32 and then back to String??
Simply do this:

```
if (errCheck[i].IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault() == true)
    err = "1"+err;
else 
    err = "0"+err;
_serialPort.Write("<16,"+ err + ">");
```

Even Uint32 can't take 32 digits!

And in your arduino code you are using atoi too. Handle it as a String. Why do u need it as a integer?

Btw thing about using enums for bitwise operations for examples look here:
http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/

Comment: You're right it doesn't have any sense converting it to uint32, but this does not solve my problem, I'm still getting the same results

Comment: Ok so what is in err exactly? and how do you parse your message in arduino? maybe you could update that in you question :)